# System.IO.EndOfStreamException when scaffolding Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL database

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am trying to scaffold an existing Postgres database with the following command

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "<connection string>" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -v
```

Which results in the exception below:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream
> ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlReadBuffer.g__EnsureLong|41_0(NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, Int32 count, Boolean async, Boolean readingNotifications)
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlReadBuffer.g__EnsureLong|41_0(NpgsqlReadBuffer buffer, Int32 count, Boolean async, Boolean readingNotifications)
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.g__OpenCore|191_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
> at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection dbConnection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
> at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluarlize)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

I'm using `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` on version `6.0.7`

Can anyone help? I've searched and can't find a solution to this problem

Comment: Looks like a problem connecting to the database. Are you certain your connection string is ok?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I check my projects ***dependencies*** in my solution.
I deleted extra and unused dependencies and then, I made the version used for each dependency the same in all projects and the problem solved!
My be it works for you, too.